# "COM_CONTENT_created_DATE" does not show translation

Tags: language

I am using the FJRelated plugin. There is a menu item for fjrelated to display a page almost the same as Joomla's default Category List.

I have this line:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'COM_FJRELATED_'.$date.'_DATE', $dateOrder, $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
```

which I change to:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'COM_CONTENT_'.$date.'_DATE', $dateOrder, $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
```

but in the front end I see the string **COM_CONTENT_CREATED_DATE** instead of the actual translation.

In Joomla's default_articles.php there is the same line:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort', 'COM_CONTENT_' . $date . '_DATE', 'a.created', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
```

which works perfectly fine in the front end.

I do not remember anything else to be needed in order to use Joomla's language strings in any custom php page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load `com_content` language file.

```
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_content');
```

Comment: yes! that did it. i placed it in the same file override in my template folder. I guess it is correct since it won't get overwritten in future updates. right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.